# Возможна ли передача аргументов из основного кода в VKScript (метод execute)

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, vkscript

Пишу скрипт-парсер на Python, который должен собрать всю историю сообщений из беседы. Планирую реализовать данную идею через метод execute (библиотека "vk") и появился вопрос по поводу передачи аргументов в execute-код.
Могу ли я как-нибудь обеспечить передачу параметра offset в code?

```
reponse_get_history = 
apivk.messages.getHistory(peer_id=2000000590,offset=0,count=200,v=5.92)
response_execute = []

count_message = 0

while count_message < reponse_get_history["count"]:

  code = '''
  var i = 0;
  var response_get_history = [];
  var response_get_history_message = [];
  var offset = 0;
  while (i < 25) 
  {
    response_get_history = response_get_history_message + API.messages.getHistory({"peer_id": 2000000590, "offset": offset, "count": 200});
    response_get_history_message = response_get_history_message + response_get_history.items;
    i = i + 1;
    offset = offset + 200;
  }
  return response_get_history_message;
  '''

  response_execute = response_execute + apivk.execute(code=code, v=5.92)
  count_message = count_message + len(response_execute)

  print(response_execute)

  time.sleep(50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы хотите изменять значение переменной offset в строке code? Это можно сделать с помощью форматирования строки. Для этого необходимо отметить в строке места, которые потом должны быть заполнены другими значениями с помощью метода `format()`. Места для заполнения отмечаются фигурными скобками `{}`.

Обратите внимание на `var offset = {};` - это та часть, которая будет заполняться новыми значениями при форматировании. Также нужно экранировать фигурные скобки, которые не являются областями для форматирования и просто должны отображаться в итоговой строке - `{{` и `}}`.

```
code = '''
var i = 0;
var response_get_history = [];
var response_get_history_message = [];
var offset = {};
while (i < 25) 
{{
    response_get_history = response_get_history_message + API.messages.getHistory({{"peer_id": 2000000590, "offset": offset, "count": 200}});
    response_get_history_message = response_get_history_message + response_get_history.items;
    i = i + 1;
    offset = offset + 200;
}}
return response_get_history_message;
'''

offset = 13
print(code.format(offset))
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно передавать аргументы вместе с запросом. А получить их внутри VKScript можно при помощи магического объекта `Args`.

Пример на `requests`:

```py
import requests

r = requests.post("https://api.vk.com/method/execute", data={
    "access_token": "***",
    "v": "5.131",
    "code": "return Args.test;",
    "test": "StackOverflow"
})

print(r.json())
```

В ответ мы получим: `{'response': 'StackOverflow'}`.

---

Эта возможность в первую очередь используется в [хранимых процедурах](https://dev.vk.com/mini-apps/management/procedures) приложения, но её можно использовать и в обычном методе `execute`.